# shell variable substitution issue

Tags: bash, sh, ksh

I have a command output a file path name starting with a variable, such as $DIR1/file1. I assign this path name to a variable pname, now when I use the path to read the file, the variable substitution doesn't work. To simulate the case,

```
-> cat paths.log
$DIR1/file1

-> DIR1=/var/tmp
-> touch $DIR1/file1
-> pname=`cat paths.log`
-> echo $pname
$DIR1/file1

-> ls -l $pname
$DIR1/file1: No such file or directory
```

Anyone knows how to workaround this problem?

Comment: Please don't mix script with output (you can use `>` or `$` before commands to let us know you're showing us an interactive session).

Comment: Or actually, you're more interested in the order of expansions here: see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions. Parameter expansion occurs *before* command substitution, so the `$DIR1` in `$pname` is a literal string, rather than expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use eval to effect expansion of variables inside a string.  Here I set `expanded` to the results of the expansion:

```
$ pname='$DIR1/file1'
$ echo $pname
$DIR1/file1
$ DIR1=/var/tmp
$ expanded=`eval echo $pname`
$ echo $expanded
/var/tmp/file1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with the `envsubst` command and avoid the dangers of `eval` like so:

```
$ cat path.log
$DIR1/file1

$ export DIR1=/var/tmp
$ pname=$(envsubst < path.log)
$ printf "%s\n" "$pname"
/var/tmp/file1
```

Note that you have to export `DIR1` for this to work, not just assign it.